# JS template language that allows me to determine path

Tags: javascript, templates, dust.js, handlebars.js

I am currently looking for JS templating language that does something very specific. Many JS templating languages (like handlebars and dust) allow you to iterate over items in a collection or directly specify paths, but I want to take also get the complete path of the data.

For example, if I were given the following data:-

```
{
  people: [
    {firstName: "Test", lastName: "One"},
    {firstName: "John", lastName: "Smith"}
  ]
}
```

I would want to create a template like this:-

```
<div id="people">
  {{#each people}}
    <div>
      <span data-path="<<<PATH SYNTAX FOR firstName>>>">{{firstName}}</span>
      <span data-path""<<<PATH SYNTAX FOR lastName>>>"">{{lastName}}</span>
    </div>
  {{/each}}
</div>
```

Which would give me this:-

```
<div id="people">
   <div>
      <span data-path="people[0].firstName">Test</span>
      <span data-path="people[0].lastName">One</span> 
   </div>
   <div>
      <span data-path="people[1].firstName">John</span>
      <span data-path="people[1].lastName">Smith</span> 
   </div>
</div>
```

Is this even possible? I would prefer to use something without a very JS heavy syntax. Something similar to handlebars or dust. In fact, if someone can suggest how to make handlebars or dust do what I am asking, that would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you trying to do this in a specific way or in a generic way?

Answer (score 2):

I think this is doable with **dustjs**. This is one of simplest ways to get the output which you expect.

```
<div id="people">
  {#people}
    <div>
      <span data-path="people[{$idx}].firstName">{.firstName}</span>{~n}
      <span data-path="people[{$idx}].lastName">{.lastName}</span>{~n}
    </div>
  {/people}
</div>
```

Or you can create a custom helper which can produce the expected output.

```
var dust = require("dustjs-linkedin");
require("dustjs-helpers");

dust.helpers.PrintName = function(chunk, context, bodies, params) {
    var Data = params.dataItem.split("."), i, len;
    for (i = 0, len = Data.length; i < len; i += 1) {
        chunk.write(Data[i]);
        if (i === len - 2) {
            chunk.write("[" + context.stack.tail.head.$idx + "]");
        }
        if (i !== len - 1) {
            chunk.write(".");
        }
    }
    return chunk;
};
```

And the template looks like this,

```
<div id="people">{~n}
  {#people}
    <div>{~n}
      <span data-path="{@PrintName dataItem="people.firstName"/}">{.firstName}</span>{~n}
      <span data-path="{@PrintName dataItem="people.lastName" /}">{.lastName}</span>{~n}
    </div>{~n}
  {/people}
</div>{~n}
```